# Bring whole blocks in order

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a query that looks like

```
SELECT
    a, b, c, d
FROM
    tab
ORDER BY
    a ASC, b ASC
```

And my result set looks like

```
+-----------------------+
|  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |
+-----------------------+
|  A1 |  B1 |  X  | null|
|  A1 |  B2 |  X  | null|
|  A1 |  B3 |  X  | null|
|  A1 |  B4 |  X  | date|
|  A2 |  B1 |  X  | null|
|  A2 |  B2 |  X  | null|
|  A2 |  B3 |  X  | null|
|  A2 |  B4 |  X  | date|
...
```

where `X` can be anything (doesn't matter here). I want to order these blocks `A1`, `A2` etc. by date in column `d` without changing the order among blocks (so that `B1` is still before `B2`, ...).

Any suggestions? Or is this approach going in the wrong direction?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that would only order dates in a ordered b-block, not rearrange the whole blocks (i.e. A2 before A1)

Comment: then remove `a` as the first order column.

Comment: But then I don't have all A1s together with correct Bs lined up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I guess right you want to sort blocks by `MAX(D)` for whole block (or MIN(d) ?).
Try this query then:

```
SELECT T.* 
FROM T
JOIN (SELECT a, MAX(d) as maxD 
        FROM T 
        GROUP BY a) as T1
  ON T.a=T1.a
ORDER BY T1.maxD,T.a,T.b
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/a1dff/2)</kbd>

Comment: `ORDER BY MAX(d) OVER (PARTITION BY a), a, b` Should be more efficient http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a1dff/6

Comment: Thanks! That did the job as I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

This should be *much* simpler with `max()` as [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY max(d) OVER (PARTITION BY a), a, b;
```